# Using variables as function parameters in VBA, specifically Cells() Function

Tags: python, arrays, vba, loops, variables

I am working with loops & arrays in VBA.

I watched a bunch of videos online and none of the instructors have gone over this.

In Python, you can dynamically access values from an array by setting the index of my variable:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = 0

while(b < len(array1)):
  print(array1[b])
  b = b + 1
```

You can do something similar with pandas indexing iloc capability....this way I can change the variable _currentRow7 to whatever I want....I just need to do `_currentRow7 = _currentrow7+1`

```
Array.iloc[_currentRow7, 11])
```

With the VBA Cells function, I get an error. Essentially I want to access values from Excel dynamically. For example - Cells(variable, 1)....then as the variable changes, I am accessing the value in the next cell.

```vb
Sub HomeRunCounterFNCTN()

Dim HomeRuns(27) As Integer
Dim HRCounter As Variant

Worksheets("Baseball").Activate
Range("L3").Activate
For HRCounter = 0 To 27

    HomeRuns(HRCounter) = ActiveCell.Offset(HRCounter, 0).Value
    If (HomeRuns(HRCounter) >= 45) Then MsgBox (HomeRuns(HRCounter))
    MsgBox (Cells(HRCounter & 1))

Next HRCounter

End Sub
```

Essentially I would like the MsgBox (Cells(HRCounter & 1)) to update dynamically as the variable HRCounter changes.

Comment: What do you mean by `HRCounter & 1` ?  Also, if you're getting an error, it's useful to describe the error and tell us where it occurs.

Comment: `Cells` is a read only property that returns a `range` object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code without error, so as @Tim Williams says, it would be helpful to describe the error you are getting.

I did spot one non-fatal flaw in this line:

```
MsgBox (Cells(HRCounter & 1)
```

You probably meant `Cells(HRCounter, 1)`. The typo doesn't cause a program error, but the line fails to capture what you intended to capture.

Aside from the typo, the code seems to do what you intended it to do. However, to answer your question more directly, you can certainly work with variable cell references. In basic pattern, simply use `SomeWorksheet.Cells(MyVar,1).Value`, where MyVar is the variable holding your row number.

To write efficient VBA code, learn to avoid `Activate` and `Select` whenever possible. Think of them as code imitating the actions of a human user, which is rarely required. Instead, work directly with Excel objects and their properties. Your code can be recast as follows, which will also make the use of a variable row reference more visible:

```
Sub HomeRunCounterFNCTN()
    
    Dim HomeRuns(27) As Integer, ReadRow As Integer
    Dim HRCounter As Variant
    
    With Worksheets("Baseball")
    
        For HRCounter = 0 To 27
            ReadRow = HRCounter + 3
            HomeRuns(HRCounter) = .Cells(ReadRow, 12).Value
            If (HomeRuns(HRCounter) >= 45) Then MsgBox HomeRuns(HRCounter)
        Next HRCounter
    
    End With

End Sub
```